# Encapsulating retries into `with` block

Tags: python, exception, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm looking to encapsulate logic for database transactions into a `with` block; wrapping the code in a transaction and handling various exceptions (locking issues). This is simple enough, however I'd like to also have the block encapsulate the retrying of the code block following certain exceptions. I can't see a way to package this up neatly into the context manager.

*Is it possible to repeat the code within a `with` statement?*

I'd like to use it as simply as this, which is really neat.

```
def do_work():
    ...
    # This is ideal!
    with transaction(retries=3):
        # Atomic DB statements
        ...
    ...
```

I'm currently handling this with a decorator, but I'd prefer to offer the context manager (or in fact both), so I can choose to wrap a few lines of code in the `with` block instead of an inline function wrapped in a decorator, which is what I do at the moment:

```
def do_work():
    ...
    # This is not ideal!
    @transaction(retries=3)
    def _perform_in_transaction():
        # Atomic DB statements
        ...
    _perform_in_transaction()
    ...
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html looks like it has examples on how to implement a context manager.

Answer (score 16):

> Is it possible to repeat the code within a `with` statement?

[No.](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-May/020633.html)

As pointed out earlier in that mailing list thread, you can reduce a bit of duplication by making the decorator call the passed function:

```
def do_work():
    ...
    # This is not ideal!
    @transaction(retries=3)
    def _perform_in_transaction():
        # Atomic DB statements
        ...
    # called implicitly
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, shame it's not supported. Thanks for the link to the thread. I like the idea of having the call implicit to make it cleaner. If I want to set/modify vars within `_perform_in_transaction`, I guess I'll have to call it manually anyway and return what I need to continue the rest of the `do_work` function.

Answer (score 7):

The way that occurs to me to do this is just to implement a standard database transaction [context manager](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types), but allow it to take a `retries` argument in the constructor. Then I'd just wrap that up in your method implementations. Something like this:

```
class transaction(object):
    def __init__(self, retries=0):
        self.retries = retries
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        pass

    # Implementation...
    def execute(self, query):
        err = None
        for _ in range(self.retries):
            try:
                return self._cursor.execute(query)
            except Exception as e:
                err = e # probably ought to save all errors, but hey
        raise err

with transaction(retries=3) as cursor:
    cursor.execute('BLAH')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate where `_cursor` in `self._cursor` comes from?

Comment: @MikeMüller I'm trying to draw on some common database API customs without getting bogged down in implementation details. `_cursor` is meant to be a [`Cursor`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects) object, as appropriate for the particular database connection involved. A full implementation would need to create and contain a `Connection` object of some kind, in order to actually carry out the database transactions.

Comment: @HenryKeller I would have done something like this `def __init__(self, cursor, retries=0):` and inside the `__init__` this `self._cursor = cursor'. Usage: `with transaction(cursor, retries=3) as cursor:`. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MikeMüller Certainly. That's what I mean by my comment regarding "a full implementation": to do this fully, it would probably be best either to make a space in the constructor for a `Connection` or `Cursor`, or else make the constructor something like `def __init__(self, dbhost, dbname, user, password):` and create a `Connection` object from there. I'm not including that stuff in the answer because it's not really relevant to the OP's question, which is specifically about repeating code automatically with a context manager, not creating a DB context manager in the first place.

Comment: This is a rather elaborate way to pass 3 as a parameter to `execute()`. Why not just `def execute(self, query, retries=1)`, and call it `cursor.execute(query, 3)`?

Comment: @Oddthinking You're right that that's equivalent. The reason (in my mind) for making it a transaction parameter is just so that you don't have to specify `retries` for every query you might want to execute within that transaction.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As decorators are just functions themselves, you could do the following:

```
with transaction(_perform_in_transaction, retries=3) as _perf:
    _perf()
```

For the details, you'd need to implement `transaction()` as a factory method that returns an object with `__callable__()` set to call the original method and repeat it up to `retries` number of times on failure; `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` would be defined as normal for database transaction context managers.

You could alternatively set up `transaction()` such that it itself executes the passed method up to `retries` number of times, which would probably require about the same amount of work as implementing the context manager but would mean actual usage would be reduced to just `transaction(_perform_in_transaction, retries=3)` (which is, in fact, equivalent to the decorator example delnan provided).

Answer (score 3):

While I agree it can't be done with a context manager... it can be done with *two* context managers!

The result is a little awkward, and I am not sure whether I approve of my own code yet, but this is what it looks like as the client:

```
with RetryManager(retries=3) as rm:
    while rm:
        with rm.protect:
            print("Attempt #%d of %d" % (rm.attempt_count, rm.max_retries))
             # Atomic DB statements
```

There is an explicit `while` loop still, and not one, but two, `with` statements, which leaves a little too much opportunity for mistakes for my liking.

Here's the code:

```
class RetryManager(object):
    """ Context manager that counts attempts to run statements without
        exceptions being raised.
        - returns True when there should be more attempts
    """

    class _RetryProtector(object):
        """ Context manager that only raises exceptions if its parent
            RetryManager has given up."""
        def __init__(self, retry_manager):
            self._retry_manager = retry_manager

        def __enter__(self):
            self._retry_manager._note_try()
            return self

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
            if exc_type is None:
                self._retry_manager._note_success()
            else:
                # This would be a good place to implement sleep between
                # retries.
                pass

            # Suppress exception if the retry manager is still alive.
            return self._retry_manager.is_still_trying()

    def __init__(self, retries=1):

        self.max_retries = retries
        self.attempt_count = 0 # Note: 1-based.
        self._success = False

        self.protect = RetryManager._RetryProtector(self)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        pass

    def _note_try(self):
        self.attempt_count += 1

    def _note_success(self):
        self._success = True

    def is_still_trying(self):
        return not self._success and self.attempt_count < self.max_retries

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.is_still_trying()
```

---

Bonus: I know you don't want to separate your work off into separate functions wrapped with decorators... but if you *were* happy with that, the [redo](https://github.com/mozilla-releng/redo) package from Mozilla offers the decorators to do that, so you don't have to roll your own. There is even a Context Manager that effective acts as temporary decorator for your function, but it still relies on your retrievable code to be factored out into a single function.

Comment: Hmm... I think we could simplify this slightly to just be a `for retry in Retry(retries=3): with retry:`, so only two outer blocks.

Comment: @user295691: I can't fault that. Seems like an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

This question is a few years old but after reading the answers I decided to give this a shot.

This solution requires the use of a "helper" class, but I I think it does provide an interface with retries configured through a context manager.

```py
class Client:
    def _request(self):
        # do request stuff
        print("tried")
        raise Exception()

    def request(self):
        retry = getattr(self, "_retry", None)
        if not retry:
            return self._request()
        else:
            for n in range(retry.tries):
                try:
                    return self._request()
                except Exception:
                    retry.attempts += 1


class Retry:
    def __init__(self, client, tries=1):
        self.client = client
        self.tries = tries
        self.attempts = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        self.client._retry = self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print(f"Tried {self.attempts} times")
        del self.client._retry
```

```
>>> client = Client()
>>> with Retry(client, tries=3):
    ... # will try 3 times
    ... response = client.request()

tried once
tried once
tried once
Tried 3 times
```

Comment: It seems as an overcomplication for me: moving `tries` and `attempts` into `Client` class makes `Retry` helper redundant. Moreover, this will make the whole implementation readability much better ;)